# Spring Boot Data JPA JpaRepository Transaction Management on custom delete methods

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I run into a weird behaviour while working on a service method. A delete method in a JPA Repository defined by method name is not transactional while custom delete methods need to be annotated with @Modifying and @Transactional. This leads to weird behaviour.

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {

  @Query(value = "DELETE FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.otherEntity.Id = ?1")
  @Modifying
  @Transactional
  void deleteAllByOtherEntityId(String requestNumber);

  void deleteAllByOtherEntity_Id(String requestNumber);
}
```

When I call them in my service method which is also transactional, the custom delete method will create a new transaction according to transaction manager logs while the method delete method created by method name is not transactional

> No need to create transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.deleteAllByOtherEntity_Id]:
> This method is not transactional.

The problem here is with rollbacks. The first method commits its transaction and rollbacks will not affect it. The second method works fine with rollbacks.

Now at the moment this is fine for me because the second method works for me but I am wondering if this behaviour is intendet or if I am missing something.

best, m

Edit:
Actually there seems to be a problem with my config. Also JPA Methods (even read-only) create their own transactions.

> Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findById]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly

I didn't see it before because I was trying out things and had set

```
enabledefaulttransactions=false
```

Comment: It will not start a new transaction, despite the logs, and it should participate in the current transaction. If that doesn' thappen there is something weird in your setup.

Comment: I can't see whats weird in the setup. Transactions seem to work generally. They are participating for read-only methods like find*()

Answer (score 0):

The point is: you set the Transactional here:

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {

  @Query(value = "DELETE FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.otherEntity.Id = ?1")
  @Modifying
  @Transactional //<-- Hier you set the Transactional (but its wrong)
  void deleteAllByOtherEntityId(String requestNumber);

  void deleteAllByOtherEntity_Id(String requestNumber);
}
```

if you want to role Back so you must delete here the Transactional AND SET IT ON THE METHOD in which you logic goes.

for Example:

```
@Transactional
public void hereIdoSomethingAndNeedRollBack(){

}
```

What i Mean:

i mean if you use  `void deleteAllByOtherEntityId(String requestNumber);` then you must delete the @transactional after `@Modifying` in your Repository Class and set the `@Transactional` ONLY on your Method! if you use `deleteAllByOtherEntity_Id` (so you do it over the Method Name) you dont need the `@Transactional` on Method

Comment: I do, see my original post

"When I call them in my service method which is also transactional"

Comment: yes but it should not ALSO it should ONLY on the method.

Comment: JpaRepository are Transactional by default. Thats not something I can change.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleJpaRepository is transactional by default but with readOnly=true. As you have marked your service class as transactional, that annotation is going to overried this behaviour.

In your repository class you don't need to necessarily mark any method as transactional but you sure need to mark the custom update method as @Modifying.

The rollback issue might have two reasons.

1. If no custom rollback rules are configured in this annotation, the transaction will roll back on RuntimeException and Error but not on checked exceptions.
2. You might not be calling the custom method properly from service class so that it is not allowing you to rollback the transaction.